# Dialog Flow CX, pricing, by session? by request?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I would like to understand what price will generate my chatboot developed in Dialog Flow CX.
I have read the page https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/pricing but it is not entirely clear to me.

With Dialogflow CX, you pay per session? by request?
And that is considered a request?

A request is generated every time that the end user writes a question in the chat bot?
Or a request is equal to a session?

According to the price page, $0.007 per request.

For example:

- A user opens a conversation with the chatbot
- And ask 5 questions, with its 5 responses from the chatbot
  What price would it generate?
  $0.007 by one session
  or $0.007 by questions? $0.007 x 5 = $0,035

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming but rather about customer service. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/pricing#table) documentation, a request is defined as any call to the Dialogflow service. Note that a request is not equivalent to a session - a session may consist of multiple requests.

Moreover, also note that a new Dialogflow CX pricing model (2021-09) will take effect on September 1, 2021 - customers will be charged per request. Until that date, the original prices (2020-09) are in effect - customers are currently charged per session.

For your example, where the end-user asks 5 questions by sending text requests to a chatbot and receives 5 responses from the Dialogflow CX agent, this counts as 5 text requests, and the cost would be:

- CX Agent (2020-09) (current): **$20 per 100 chat sessions**

  - If you have 5 requests that are sent by the same end-user, it is considered as 1 session only. Hence, the cost will be **$0.20**.
  - If you have 5 requests where each request is sent by different end-users, it is considered as 5 sessions. Hence, the cost will be **$1**.
- CX Agent (2021-09) (starting September 1, 2021): $0.007 x 5 = **$0.035**

Basically, each time an end-user sends a query to the agent, the Dialogflow API’s [detectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api#detect-intent) or [StreamingDetectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/how/detect-intent-stream) method gets called and that counts as one text request or one audio request, depending on whether the application sends text or voice data to Dialogflow.

Answer (score 0):

so for the most recent CX Agent (2021) you will pay $0.007 per request, so using your example if a user asks 5 questions thats 0.007*5 = $0.035.

If you're using a 2020 CX Agent you'd be paying $20 per 100 sessions, a session would be any conversation the agent would have with one user. So if your user asked 100 questions it would still be considered one session.